# Android - Best practice for building table of views in XML layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to build a table of views that will match both the height and width of the screen.
The margin between views should grow as the screen grows.
I tried to do it using weights but weights control either width or height, not both at the same time. And nested weights are bad for performance..
This is what I'm trying to achieve more or less -

[image]

And this is what I've tried so far:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".SomeActivity" >

<View
  android:id="@+id/content"
  .../>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/content2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/memory_card_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/memory_card_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/memory_card_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/memory_card_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/memory_card_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/memory_card_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/memory_card_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/memory_card_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thirdRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/memory_card_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/memory_card_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/memory_card_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/memory_card_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<View
 android:id="@+id/content2" />
```

I used 3 horizontal LinearLayouts inside on vertical LinearLayout. Each of the 3 horizontal LaynearLayouts has layout_weight.

Please tell me if I forgot to mention something. 
Thanks.

Comment: It seems you are looking for a GridView...

Comment: Isn't it a waist when there's no recycling? The views don't change or move..
I'm asking, don't really know since I've never used a GridView..

Comment: No, it's not a waste. It's surely more efficient than having nested layouts (specially if using nested weights!).

Comment: Try it it's easy. Same as a ListView, more or less.

Comment: Did you have doubts? ;)